# How should I organize programming files into directories?

Tags: organization, file-structure

Sometimes, one creates a exploratory prototype and forgets about structure in the directories...

What are good tips on dividing the programming files over (several levels of) directories?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your language is OOP and package based (Eg Java), then you should probably keep each package in its own folder (eg `my/package/name`) to keep with the convention.

If your language isn't package based (Eg PHP), then organize by what each file does. Here's an example

- Does this do utility functions? Goes in `/util`
- Is this a 3rd party plugin? Goes in `/plugin`
- Is this part of the admin panel? Goes in `/admin`, along with ALL supporting files
- Is this Javascript? Goes in `/javascript`
- Is this CSS? Goes in `/css`
- Is this a template? Goes in `/templates/templateName`
- etc

Language agnostic, Most people have a `/src` directory for all source files, a `/lib` directory for libraries, and a `/bin` or `/dist` directory for builds.

Comment: Why not a `build` directory for builds?